Using hashes for Content Security Policy in statically generated sites (SSG) in Next.js 13.5
I'm trying to understand how to implement a strict CSP in Next.js 13.5 using SSG. This is a simple informational site under 20 pages including a locally-served MDX blog. It's JS based, not Typescript. I don't require server-side rendering and would like to avoid it. This should be possible with a hash-based CSP. But the Next.js documentation only addresses strict CSP with SSR and nonces:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy
I'm particularly puzzled by this section in the above doc:
"For applications that do not require nonces, you can set the CSP header directly in your next.config.js file:"
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src 'self' blob: data:;
    font-src 'self';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    form-action 'self';
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    upgrade-insecure-requests;
`
 
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: cspHeader.replace(/\n/g, ''),
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

I did that, but Lighthouse and all other SEO tools are flagging the configuration as unsecure due to all the unsafe declarations.
So my questions are:

How do I determine whether my site 'requires nonces' as stated in the
Next.js docs? The config in the example isn't strict CSP because of
unsafe-inline and Google could conceivably flag it in a Pure Spam
action.
How can I achieve strict CSP with hashes using Javascript with Next.js and SSG?
And finally:
What good is SSG if there's no way to conform to Google guidelines for strict CSP? Doesn't that make SSG basically useless from a security standpoint?

Thanks for any help.
